# Converting maximization to minimization in aproximation algorithms

Tags: algorithms, optimization, approximation

Suppose algorithm *A* is given for a maximization problem and we are asked to show that it is a 1/2-approximation algorithm.

As you know it is enough to show

Sol >= 1/2 OPT

What I need to know is, is it true to assume this problem as a minimization one and prove

Sol <= 2 OPT

Or is there any correspondence between these two?

Comment: What does  "assume this problem as a minimization one" mean/entail?

Comment: @Raphael as *Yuval* said I mean to consider reciprocal of function instead of the function itself,  or if it some maximization problem, say *cardinality maximum cut* then we consider *cardinality minimum cut* problem

Comment: Yuval also said that that is not possible, at least not as easily as you seem to think it is.

Comment: @Raphael You are right, moreover when approximate algorithm $A$ is designed for a maximization, we need to find an upper bound to show its approximation factor while if we assume it is minimization we must find a lower bound which is impossible to do this for $A$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One connection is that maximizing some function $f$ is the same as minimizing its reciprocal $1/f$. You can use this to convert between maximization and minimization.

The general problem of maximizing a function $f$ under some constraints can be very different from the corresponding minimization problem (of the *same* function $f$). A case in point is MIN-CUT versus MAX-CUT. Whereas MIN-CUT is in P, MAX-CUT is NP-hard to approximate better than some constant.

Comment: Shortest vs. longest path is another example.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So in the case of approximation algorithms we have to work on the minimum version of the problem. Therefore if algorithm *A* is given for a maximization problem, say *cardinality maximum cut* we cannot use its corresponding minimization, *cardinality minimum cut*,  because algorithm *A* is given for a maximization problem not a minimization one, and by analyzing the algorithm we will get an upper bound (in case of maximization) of OPT not a lower bound (in case of minimization). Am I right?

Comment: Some optimization problems are maximizations, other are minimizations. You have to work on the problem as given. Switching the objective results in a different problem which can have a very different complexity.